# How to check two variables with 'and' operator in jstl

Tags: jstl

How to check two variable with and condition in when tag

```
<c:when test="${preferences.vipUsers != 'null' && preferences.vipUsers!='' && preferences.vipUsers eq 'false'} && ${FieldVipUsers_Birthday eq 'false'}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
<c:when test="${not empty preferences.vipUsers && FieldVipUsers_Birthday == false}">
```